# AKKA Classic remoting - Discarding inbound message to [unknown] in read-only association to [XX]

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-remoting

I am using AKKA classic remoting due to a legacy application with no intention to upgrade to using typed/artery.
On the 2.6.10 version we have recently been getting the following message in the logs

```
a.r.EndpointReader:90 - Discarding inbound message to [unknown] in read-only association to [akka.tcp://actorSystem@{{valid url address}}:{{valid port}}]. If this happens often you may consider using akka.remote.use-passive-connections=off or use Artery TCP.
```

Can someone explain why this log line is recently coming out? We have only just noticed it but it could be due to an upgrade from 2.5.25 to 2.6.10, but I don't understand what could be causing this line to come out. I am nervous to use the suggested property without understanding why it is failing in the first place when it hasnt been for years.

Extra info:
The cluster is set up with 2 nodes where just one of the nodes is outputting this message. It is happening when sending a message directly to one of the nodes (message is output on either the sender node or the receiver node - but more generally it is the receiver node).